# Web Api - Request Parameters Outside Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, asp.net-web-api, httpcontext

I'm working on a ASP.NET Web Api project and made it accept version information in the url.

For example:

> - api/v1/MyController
> - api/v2/MyController

Now I would like to get the request version **v1, v2** inside a custom LayoutRenderer for `Nlog`. Normally I would do this like the below example.

```
[LayoutRenderer("Version")]
public class VersionLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(System.Text.StringBuilder builder, NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var version = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Version"];
        builder.Append(version);
    }
}
```

**The problem:** `HttpContext.Current` is NULL

I believe this is because I use [Async wrappers](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Targets/Target.cs) for `NLog` and some calls before the Logger are also `Async`.

A example of the logger being called Async inside Ninject.Extensions.WebApi.UsageLogger. At this point the `HttpRequestMessage` has all info we need to get the Version.

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UsageHandler" /> class.
/// </summary>
public UsageHandler()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    var logfactory = kernel.Get<ILoggerFactory>();

    this.Log = logfactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
}

protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;

        // Log request
        await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(c =>
            {
                this.Log.Info("{0}: {1} called from {2}", request.Method, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri), ((HttpContextBase)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.UserHostAddress);
                this.Log.Info("Content-Type: {0}, Content-Length: {1}", request.Content.Headers.ContentType != null ? request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType : string.Empty, request.Content.Headers.ContentLength);
                this.Log.Info("Accept-Encoding: {0}, Accept-Charset: {1}, Accept-Language: {2}", request.Headers.AcceptEncoding, request.Headers.AcceptCharset, request.Headers.AcceptLanguage);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Result))
                {
                    if (this.MaxContentLength > 0 && c.Result.Length > this.MaxContentLength)
                    {
                        this.Log.Info("Data: {0}", HttpUtility.UrlDecode(c.Result).Substring(0, this.MaxContentLength - 1));
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        this.Log.Info("Data: {0}", HttpUtility.UrlDecode(c.Result));
                    }
                }
            });

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Log the error if it returned an error
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            this.Log.Error(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }

        // Log performance
        this.Log.Info("Request processing time: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds + "s");

        return response;
    }
```

**The question**
What would be the best way to make the `VersionLayoutRenderer` work in a **generic** way? Could I add a MessageHandler and Bind the HttpRequest to some Async scope? If so any guidelines would be much appreciated cause I'm still getting used to `Ninject`.

For the time being I add the version information directly to the Log Call in the UsageHandler, but I would really like a more generic solution, where I can always rely on version information inside my logging.

**Edit:** Updated the question to be more specific and included more details.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're using async

Comment: Jonathan, please see the updated question I hope it contains all the information you need and otherwise please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual issue is really neutral wrt what you should do with Ninject - you just need to get the phasing of your processing such that any objects that are going be running async have everything they need without relying on the magic `HttpContext.Current`. Get that working with no DI Container first.

Then, to use Ninject the major steps are:-

1. Your `Bind` statements need to be run once. See the Ninject.MV3 wiki for the best approach (until it gets merged in, there is not OOTB with the NuGet-based edition)
2. as @rickythefox (+1'd) says, your registration should bake the thread/context-relative data into the object and you config the registration such that it can happen early in request processing, when you're still on the thread that's `HttpContext.Current`

   ```
   kernel.Bind<ILogger>()
   // TODO replace GCCL with something like GetClassLogger(ctx.Request.Service.ReflectedType) - see the wiki for examples
     .ToMethod( ctx=> ctx.Get<ILoggerFactory>().GetCurrentClassLogger()) 
     .InRequestScope()
     .WithConstructorArgument("context",c=>HttpContext.Current);
   ```

Then just make the constructor of the handler take a `ILogger`, which can be assigned to `.Log` (which I hope isnt `static` :D)

NB, the aim is for you never to write a `kernel.Get()`, ever, period.

The real problem here though, is that proper use of WebApi does not involve using `HttpContext.Current` or any other magic `static` methods or anything similar (for testability, to make yourself independent of the hosting context (self hosting, OWIN etc), and many more reasons).

Also, if you are using NLog (or Log4Net) you should also look at the `Ninject.Extensions.Logging` package (and source).

Comment: Ruben Thanks for your answer. I accepted it because it is constructive and made me realise that I'd rather not go the way I was thinking about. I wanted a `generic` solution to have some extra data when I was logging. But since this data is not always available it will always be a little tricky. I will just make a messagehandler that writes some call info to a database with Nlog. Also I am using `Ninject.Extensions.Logging` together with the `Nlog2` package, these are great packages.

Comment: @JosVinke: Good to hear you're sorted. It sure can be hard to find the simple solution when the container is sitting there offering to do all sorts of tricks for you! ... have you read http://manning.com/seemann yet? Questions like these will barely arise for you if you do - it's SO much more than a '200 page manual for a DI container' one might think it could be if you haven't read Mark Seemann's top rated posts around here...

Comment: Didn't read it, just ordered it. I'm curious but it sure looks like a nice book. Anyway thanks for the advice and feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Try injecting the context using something like:

```
kernel.Bind<IDependency>()
    .To<Mydependency>()
    .InRequestScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context",c=>HttpContext.Current);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you please be a bit more specific about how you would implement this? I'm new to Ninject and a little more help would be much appreciated! What would be the best place to bind the `IDependency` to `MyDependency`? Should I make a new `MessageHandler` and rebind the HttpContext every call?

Comment: I found out why my depency doesn't get Injected as supposed, the calls come from a async event. Any help would still be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [GlobalConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.globalconfiguration%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class can provide you access to the routing configuration.

```
// The code below assumes a map routing convention of api/{version}/{controller}/....

// This will give you the configured routes
var routes      = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes;

// This will give you the route templates
var templates   = routes
    .Select(route => route.RouteTemplate);

// This will give you the distinct versions for all controllers
var versions    = routes
    .Select(route => route.RouteTemplate)
    .Select(template => template.Split("/".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Select(values => values[1])
    .Distinct();

// This will give you the distinct versions for a controller with the specified name
var name                = "MyController";

var controllerVersions  = routes
    .Select(route => route.RouteTemplate)
    .Select(template => template.Split("/".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(values => String.Equals(values[2], name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Select(values => values[1])
    .Distinct();
```

I am not sure if you are trying to resolve the version with a known value (the name of the controller) or if you are trying to dynamically resolve it. If you inject the current HttpContext, you can use the request URI of the context to filter the routes via the route template.

**Edit:** After your comments I realized the routing configuration isn't what you were after.

If the end goal is to implement logging within your controllers, you may want to take a look at [Tracing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) as there is support for tracing built-in to the Web API infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but (correct me if I'm wrong) I dont think this helps me to get the version for the current Request. I figured that my question might be a bit vague about this so I edited it.

Comment: I think I misunderstood then. If you need the current request then injecting the HttpRequestMessage or HttpContext into the renderer makes the most sense; then you just have to parse the version out of the Request URI.

Comment: Any thought about how I should inject the HttpRequestMessage or HttpContext after a Async call? Parsing the version from the request isn't the problem pnce I have it.

Comment: Oppositional, please see the updated question I made it more specific. I'm not trying to get trace logs. I already have tracing set up and I am able to log the traces with Nlog. I want to be able to get the Version information for each item that is logged, traces, usage, log message.

Comment: This is now more accurately a Ninject question, which I unfortunately am not familiar with. Hopefully a Ninject expert can help you out.